# Raspberry Pi - Python & Flask web control with Adafruit DotStar LEDS

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, led, adafruit

apologies if this isn't the right place to ask, but I did some searching and couldn't find much to point me in the right direction. I wasn't quite sure what to search for. I am a novice with python and programming in general, but usually can do enough googling and stealing other code snippets to get my projects running. However I'm at a bit of a roadblock here.

I need to control an Adafruit DotStar lightstrip with a flask web browser app. I've been able to get the flask app working, I've done a simple proof of concept with turning an LED on and off etc., and I can start my lightstrip script but the code I'm trying to run for the lightstrip needs to loop continuously and still be able to change "modes". I have several different images that display on the light strip and I would like to be able to select which one(s) is/are playing, but for now mainly I would just like to be able to start and stop a "shuffle all" mode. If I run the module in a while loop it just loops forever and I can't change the argument to a different "mode". I built a simple script based on Adafruit's DotStar library (specifically the image persistence of vision script, I'm just using PNG images as the map for the different lightstrip "shows").

It all currently works except it only runs each mode once obviously. I had it all in a while loop and it just looped the first selected mode forever and I was unable to turn it off or switch modes. I also thought maybe I should use multiprocessing, and I looked into getting that working, but I couldn't figure out how to stop a process once it started.

Here is the light strip script:

(the 'off' mode is just a black image. I'm sure theres a cleaner way to do this but I'm not sure on how to do that either)

```
import Image
from dotstar import Adafruit_DotStar
import random

def lightstrip(mode):
    loopLength = 120        #loop length in pixels

    fade  = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/fade.png"
    sparkle = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/sparkle.png"
    steeplechase = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/steeplechase.png"
    bump = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/bump.png"
    spaz = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/spaz.png"
    sine = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/sine.png"
    bounce = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/bounce.png"
    off = "/home/pi/lightshow/images/null.png"

    numpixels = 30
    datapin   = 23
    clockpin  = 24
    strip     = Adafruit_DotStar(numpixels, 100000)

    rOffset = 3
    gOffset = 2
    bOffset = 1

    strip.begin()

    if mode == 1:
        options = [fade, sparkle, steeplechase, bump, spaz, sine, bounce]
        print "Shuffling All..."
    if mode == 2:
        options = [bump, spaz, sine, bounce]
        print "Shuffling Dance..."
    if mode == 3:
        options = [fade, sparkle, steeplechase]
        print "Shuffling Chill..."
    if mode == 0:
        choice = off
        print "Lightstrip off..."

    if mode != 0:
        choice = random.choice(options)
    print "Loading..."
    img       = Image.open(choice).convert("RGB")
    pixels    = img.load()
    width     = img.size[0]
    height    = img.size[1]
    print "%dx%d pixels" % img.size

    # Calculate gamma correction table, makes mid-range colors look 'right':
    gamma = bytearray(256)
    for i in range(256):
        gamma[i] = int(pow(float(i) / 255.0, 2.7) * 255.0 + 0.5)

    # Allocate list of bytearrays, one for each column of image.
    # Each pixel REQUIRES 4 bytes (0xFF, B, G, R).
    print "Allocating..."
    column = [0 for x in range(width)]
    for x in range(width):
        column[x] = bytearray(height * 4)

    # Convert entire RGB image into column-wise BGR bytearray list.
    # The image-paint.py example proceeds in R/G/B order because it's counting
    # on the library to do any necessary conversion.  Because we're preparing
    # data directly for the strip, it's necessary to work in its native order.
    print "Converting..."
    for x in range(width):          # For each column of image...
        for y in range(height): # For each pixel in column...
            value             = pixels[x, y]    # Read pixel in image
            y4                = y * 4           # Position in raw buffer
            column[x][y4]     = 0xFF            # Pixel start marker
            column[x][y4 + rOffset] = gamma[value[0]] # Gamma-corrected R
            column[x][y4 + gOffset] = gamma[value[1]] # Gamma-corrected G
            column[x][y4 + bOffset] = gamma[value[2]] # Gamma-corrected B

    print "Displaying..."
    count = loopLength
    while (count > 0):

        for x in range(width):         # For each column of image...
            strip.show(column[x])  # Write raw data to strip
            count = count - 1
```

And the main.py script for running the web app:

```
from flask import *
from lightshow import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Image
from dotstar import Adafruit_DotStar
import random
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/lightstrip/1", methods=['POST'])
def shuffleall():
    lightstrip(1)
    return ('', 204)

@app.route("/lightstrip/2", methods=['POST'])   
def shuffledance():
    lightstrip(2)
    return ('', 204)

@app.route("/lightstrip/3", methods=['POST'])
def shufflechill():
    lightstrip(3)
    return ('', 204)

@app.route("/lightstrip/0", methods=['POST'])
def off():
    lightstrip(0)   
    return ('', 204)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Again I'm at a bit of a loss here, this may be simple fix or I may be approaching it totally wrong but any and all help would be appreciated. I am a complete beginner to approaching a problem like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how to start and stop processes using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil). In this example the `task_runner` kills any running processes before starting a new one.

```
from flask import Flask
import multiprocessing
import psutil

app = Flask(__name__)

def blink(var):
    while True:
        # do stuff
        print(var)

def task_runner(var):
    processes = psutil.Process().children()
    for p in processes:
        p.kill()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=blink, args=(var,))
    process.start()

@app.route("/red")
def red():
    task_runner('red')
    return 'red started'

@app.route("/blue")
def blue():
    task_runner('blue')
    return 'blue started'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

For your question, the `task_runner` would look something like:

```
def task_runner(mode):
    processes = psutil.Process().children()
    for p in processes:
        p.kill()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=lightstrip, args=(mode,))
    process.start()
```